# Why the loops has a problem (pset2 Substitution)

Tags: c, cs50

I have been working CS50X pset2 substitution. I think it almost has done. When I input single char such as `A` or `B` `D` and so on... the ciphertext will get the right result. (e.g `A` will get `J`, "B" will get `T` and `D` will get `E` and so on...

However, if I input `ABC`, the ciphertext will only show `J` and the other cannot show. What did I do wrong?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int ciphertext = 0;

//Key
//JTREKYAVOGDXPSNCUIZLFBMWHQ

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
     //Check that program was run with one command-line argument
    if (argc == 2)
    {

        string key = argv[1];



        //check the key does it validate
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(key); i < n; i++)
        {

            string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
            printf("ciphertext: \n");

            int u = 64;


            for (int k = 0, p = strlen(plaintext); k < p; k++)
            {
                if (isupper(plaintext[k]) != 0)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
                    {

                        u = u + 1;
                        //printf("u is %c\n", u);


                        if (u == plaintext[k])
                        {
                            ciphertext = key[j];
                            printf("Key is %c\n", key[j]);
                            printf("Plaintext is %c\n", plaintext[k]);
                            printf("ciphertext is %c\n", ciphertext);
                            //break;
                        }

                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    printf("%c", plaintext[k]);
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you providing as the key as the first argument to the program. So how you are using it. If `argv[1]` isn't at least 26 characters, you will run into problems with your `for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)` loop indexes.

Comment: the key is "JTREKYAVOGDXPSNCUIZLFBMWHQ"

Comment: OK, and so I"m clear, you run your code as  `./program JTREKYAVOGDXPSNCUIZLFBMWHQ` and then enter the `plaintext` at the prompt, correct?

Comment: YES~ so I input the plaintext such as "ABC", the result only shows "J"... suppose it should be shows"JTE".

Comment: However, if I input "B" only, the result shows the correct answer "T"

Comment: Are you sure the keys shouldn't be `"JTR"` for `"ABC"`? Move `int u = 64;` to after `if (isupper(plaintext[k]) != 0)` so it is reinitialized for each character. (remove `int l = 96;` -- it is unused)

Comment: You also have `return 0;` **inside** your loop - remove it. Which bring up - Why are you looping `for (int i = 0, n = strlen(key); i < n; i++)` and asking for `plaintext` inside the loop? Do you want to take separate input 26 times? (it looks like you need to remove the outer loop entirely, `n` is unused)

Comment: I added a shortened version as well. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems are logic errors that appear to result from changes you attempted to make to the code that got out of hand. You have unnecessary loops and unused variable in your code. You need to change the scope of the `u` declaration so it is reinitialized on each iteration. You simply need to remove the `for (int i = 0, n = strlen(key); i < n; i++)` loop altogether, neither `i` or `n` is used. The same for `ciphertext` and `l` (ell).

You need to move `int u = 64;` immediately after `if (isupper(plaintext[k]))` so it is reset on each iteration.

I suspect all the `printf` statements were for debugging and you really only want the `key` output. Putting it altogether, you can rearrange your code to:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[]) {

    if (argc == 2) {    /* validate key given */

        string key = argv[1];
        string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        printf("ciphertext: ");

        for (int k = 0, p = strlen(plaintext); k < p; k++) 
        {
            if (isupper(plaintext[k])) 
            {
                int u = 64;
                for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) 
                {
                    u = u + 1;
                    if (u == plaintext[k]) {
                        printf("%c", key[j]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                printf("%c", plaintext[k]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cs50_cypher2 JTREKYAVOGDXPSNCUIZLFBMWHQ
plaintext: ABD
ciphertext: JTE
```

**Simplify Your Logic**

If you think about what the code above is actually doing, it can be reduced to:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {    /* validate key given */
        fputs ("usage: ./program key\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    string key = argv[1];
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("ciphertext: ");

    for (int k = 0, p = strlen(plaintext); k < p; k++) 
    {
        if (isupper(plaintext[k]))
            putchar (key[plaintext[k] - 'A']);
        else
            putchar (plaintext[k]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

Or if you use a *ternary* operator, your `for` loop condenses to simply:

```
    for (int k = 0, p = strlen(plaintext); k < p; k++) 
        putchar (isupper(plaintext[k]) ? key[plaintext[k] - 'A'] : plaintext[k]);
```

And since there is no need to call `strlen(plaintext)`, you can eliminate `string.h` entirely and just loop `for (int k = 0; plaintext[k]; k++)` since `plaintext` is a nul-terminated string, your entire program can reduce to:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {    /* validate key given */
        fputs ("usage: ./program key\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    string key = argv[1];
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext : ");
    printf("ciphertext: ");

    for (int k = 0; plaintext[k]; k++) 
        putchar (isupper(plaintext[k]) ? key[plaintext[k] - 'A'] : plaintext[k]);

    putchar ('\n');
}
```

**Handling Lowercase Letters**

You know your `key` entered as the first argument is all uppercase. So if you want to output a lowercase `key`, you must call `tolower()` on the key after you have applied the offsets. Since for an uppercase letter, you just want to know the offset within the 26-character key to use, you simply find out how many letters your current letter is from `'A'` and get that offset in `key[]`, e.g.

```
    key[plaintext[k] - 'A']
```

For lowercase input, you need to find out the offset in `key` for the difference in lowercase letters, and then apply `tolower()` to the key, e.g.

```
    tolower(key[plaintext[k] - 'a'])
```

See [ASCII Table & Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Putting that altogether, your `for` loop can be written as:

```
    for (int k = 0; plaintext[k]; k++) {
        if (isupper(plaintext[k]))
            putchar (key[plaintext[k] - 'A']);
        else if (islower(plaintext[k]))
            putchar (tolower(key[plaintext[k] - 'a']));
        else
            putchar (plaintext[k]);
    }
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cs50_cypher4 JTREKYAVOGDXPSNCUIZLFBMWHQ
plaintext : AbZ 50
ciphertext: JtQ 50
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Great! I will try to understand it! Yes, all the printf statements were for debugging purposes! Thx for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. If you get stuck - drop another comment.